# Android Calendar object issue java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no field 'serialVersionOnStream' of type int

Tags: android, serialization, calendar

I have used Calendar object inside one of the model classes. I am getting the exception

```
0   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no field 'serialVersionOnStream' of type int
1       at java.io.EmulatedFields.findMandatorySlot(EmulatedFields.java:188)
2       at java.io.EmulatedFields.put(EmulatedFields.java:458)
3       at java.io.EmulatedFieldsForDumping.put(EmulatedFieldsForDumping.java:126)
4       at java.util.Calendar.writeObject(Calendar.java:1389)
```

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: @tapani I am getting this issue while passing data model class (which contains Calendar object reference) from one activity to another and this occurs mostly on Android 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I quickly looked the Android 5.1.1 source code, but did not find a reason for this. Probably a bug in some Android source file anyway. If you don't need the timezone information use a `long` millisecond timestamp instead of `Calendar`. You can get the milliseconds from a `Calendar` object by calling `getTimeInMillis`.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-5.1.1_r34/luni/src/main/java/java/io/EmulatedFields.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-5.1.1_r34/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Calendar.java

Comment: I see this exception occurring for many fields of Calendar object. It does not occur always though. @Tapani

Comment: whats better to use Date or Calendar (gregorian calendar) in android

Comment: Date is readonly and does not have timezone or gregorian etc. calendar information. Also, Calendar has much more sophisticated methods. But you can always create a Calendar object when you need to do something to the date and then just get the Date object after you are done.